# I need to fill out cells in a series order, in ms excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have over 2K records dataset in ms excel:

```
 1045
 1045
 1045
 1083
 1083
 1083
 1083
 1088
 1088
 1088
```

Need to fill with a series values, as following:
(Please, don't pay attention on spaces. I just made them to make my goal more visible)

```
 1045 1
 1045 2
 1045 3

 1083 1
 1083 2
 1083 3
 1083 4

 1088 1
 1088 2
 1088 3
```

Please HELP !!! And Thank you, all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B1 put the following formula and copy down.

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1;A1)
```